# Search Phone numbers from Android Contact Database

Tags: android, contactscontract

I am implementing an AutocompleteView to search phone numbers. The code is working fine except in some conditions.

My Code :

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE};
    String selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " LIKE ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"%" + charSequence.toString() + "%"};
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
```

This code is working fine where there is no space in the phone numbers. For example if i enter '**123**' in my autocompleteView, it is able to find phone numbers like '9123456789' or '8283929383' but it is not able to find numbers '9123 456 789' or '912 3456 789'

I even tried implementing this with `ContactsContract.PhoneLookup` API but with this, it didnt work at all.

Code with `ContactsContract.PhoneLookup` API:

```
String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.TYPE};

Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(charSequence.toString()));

Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Instead of using `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER`, you could try to use `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER` (E164 format)

Comment: @itechevo : thanks man! It worked. you can post it as answer so that i can mark is as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER`, use `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER` (this return phone numbers in E164 format)